# Removing establishments on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am integrating Google Maps into my application, but I'm thinking that it will appear better if  I will be removing default displayed establishments on it before adding my own markers of establishments including those which are not really on Google Maps by default.

Is there any way to do this?
I've found one but it's only for Web based Google Maps.
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the MapView from the Google APIs version of the selected SDK. You can use the grid of the maps and add your custom POIs :)
The helloMaps example will guide you to understand what I mean:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: I have tried to follow the tutorial here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3


I almost finished it but I don't know where to save the HTML file (which includes JavaScript).

Please help me.

Comment: Don't follow the webview example you have google maps implementation in the MapView class. Follow this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: No sir. I am now using the webview. Thanks.

Comment: what's the benefit of using the webview and not the mapview?

Comment: Well, first of all, I decided to use the webview because Google Maps API v3 is easier to configure. I need to add my own points of interest that's why I used webview and not the mapview. Using mapview won't allow me to remove the markers of the Google Maps.

Comment: So with MapView you can draw in a Overlay your items from a List in a really easy way. Is faster because you are using Google Apis Lib. The code example is in the link above.

Comment: No, I can't use the MapView. Points of interest and other markers from the Google Maps API won't be deleted when used in a MapView.

Comment: MapView is just a Map board with the maps but not with the Google Maps API data, so you have the map to add your POIs but you don't have the POIs or markes of Google Maps service. An example is Qype he use mapview and as you can see there aren't any POI from Google Maps. Take a look https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qype.radar&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove them using Google Maps, you would need to use the Google Maps API v3 and a custom styled map that hides points of interest (POIs)

see the results of [this search](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/search?group=google-maps-js-api-v3&q=hide+pois&qt_g=Search+this+group)

Comment: I've figured this out about a minute ago(before reading your answer).
And I came up to a decision to switch to Google Maps API V3.

Well, Thanks man!