# Show blank google maps in codename one

Tags: java, google-maps, codenameone

I'm building a codename one mobile application and i need to fetch a blank google maps on which i can place icons showing my own coordinates (not places i can fetch through the google places api). How can i do that ? Since i don't want to fetch anything other than a blank map, i wonder if i need a webservice for that. I have read that instantiating the MapContainer would show me a blank google map but i am stil getting a osm map (on both the emulator and a real Android 4.4 device). I have already done all the procedures required to get a key and all the steps of the maps demo work fine for me. Now what i need to know is how to be able to get a blank map.

Thank you advance for the answers.

Comment: What do you mean by a "blank" map? All the tiles are blank?  Or just not POIs (Points of Interest) displayed?

Comment: No i don't want the tiles to be blank, just no points of interest displayed.

Comment: Answer in this question: [How to disable infowindow from registered places from map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117218/how-to-disable-infowindow-from-registered-places-from-map)

Comment: duplicate of [Removing establishments on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468996/removing-establishments-on-google-maps)

Comment: That isn't a duplicate of those since those aren't tagged Codename One...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get OSM on the device as a fallback when initializing the native map failed. Make sure you followed the integration instructions as explained [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/).

You can debug the issue on an Android device by connecting the device with a cable and launching the DDMS tool from the Android command line SDK. In 90% of the cases this means your SHA1 is different from the one defined in the maps API and this will be printed when you try to open the map.

On the simulator OSM is shown unless you provided the Google maps provider in the constructor.

Comment: It's working now.  i did not fill in the build arguments previously.  With this code : new GoogleMapsProvider(key) , i was able to get a google map with no POI both on the emulator and the Android device. Thanks Shai. But i'm not sure i understand how to debug directly on the device. Do i need Android Studio for that?

Comment: One other thing. i'm not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question but i also want to do something i asked before but the question was deleted so i'm asking again. Given at least three (latitude,longitude) couples , is there a way, i can know the approximate size of the area delimited by those points on a map? There is a google maps javascript api library called geometry which allows calculating areas sizes from web applications but there seems to be no way to query it from a webservice. Any help regarding that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with mapping technology to help you with the second question. If you don't fill the build hints you get the MapComponent fallback which is not native maps and not nearly as functional/attractive as the native maps. FYI you should accept/upvote helpful answers to improve your own ranking

Comment: There is a faded checkbox next to the answer, you need to click it so it will be green.